# How to rename only a folder with supabase js client

Tags: supabase, supabase-js

I would like to know, if it is possible to only rename a folder in supabase with the supabase js client, without finding and touching every file inside that folder.
For example here:
I want to rename folder parent to super_parent
[image]

There exists the move function in supabase js client, but there you only can rename/move files not folders. This doesn't work:

```
await supabase.storage.from("bucket_id").move(oldFolderName, newFolderName)
```

If you want to rename just a folder, you have to find all child files, child directories and there files recursive and rename every single file. Thats quite a lot of effort.

So I would like to know, if there is a shorthand version for this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to rename just a folder, because there are no folders. Each file can have a path in his name, which could be displayed as folders, but in the end, if you want to rename "folder" (part of the filename) you have to find all files in the folder and in all subfolders and rename each file by there own.